# Rename tag [kismet] to [kismet-udk]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

There are two SW called Kismet. One is an  Unreal Engine development kit tool, which has tag [kismet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kismet) and which now has a lot of questions for the other Kismet too despite the description. That other Kismet is a WLAN detector, sniffer, and intrusion detection system (which supports plugins so can have valid SO questions).

I just created tag [kismet-wireless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kismet-wireless) for the latter, and re-tagged few latest active questions. It occurs to me that the old tag could also be renamed to [kismet-udk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kismet-udk) or something like that, to remove ambiquity.

Thougths on any aspect of this?

Further actions to be taken? At least more retagging, but there are probably tools for that?

Also, was this what I did (add this tag for one meaning of an ambiguous SW name) a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: 3 new questions were asked about the wireless system, which I retagged before renaming the tag.